# Audio Cuts in random time, have to unplug headphones

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash, audiokit

Very weird "crash". I am using

```
oscillator = AKOperationGenerator(channelCount: 2, operations: { parameters in
            let portamentoOp = parameters[0].portamento(halfDuration: parameters[1])
            let sineOp = AKOperation.sineWave(frequency: portamentoOp, amplitude: parameters[2])
            let sawOp = AKOperation.sawtoothWave(frequency: portamentoOp, amplitude: parameters[2])
            return [sawOp, sineOp] //saw on left, sine on right.
        })

        oscillator?.parameters = [440.0, 0.001, 1.0, 0.99]
```

To generate tones in my app, however after couple minutes of "playing" it just stops, no crash, no error nothing. Only thing I can do is to unplug headphones and plug them back again, setup audio again and it starts.

This is logs from device:

```
default 20:32:42.906934+1200    mediaserverd    CAReportingClient.mm:470:-[CAReportingClient sendMessage:category:type:reporters:]: message {
    "inf_frames" = 0;
    "issue_type" = NonFinite;
    "nan_frames" = 1083;
    node = "PreDSP - { [ type: phpw; conn: 1; rout: 1 ] }";
    "rtaid_client" = VA;
}: (
    133143986217
)
default 20:32:42.907327+1200    mediaserverd    AudioIssueDetectorManager.cpp:250:HandleAudioIssue: RTAID [ use_case=Generic issue_type=NonFinites clientID=VA node=PreDSP - { [ type: phpw; conn: 1; rout: 1 ] } ] -- [ nan_frames=1083 inf_frames=0 ]
default 20:32:42.909321+1200    rtcreportingd   sendMessageWithDictionary: Sending message for session 41
default 20:32:42.909588+1200    rtcreportingd   <private>(sendMessage): realtime is 0
default 20:32:42.909701+1200    rtcreportingd   <private>(sendMessage): Batching 3, 1, 1
default 20:32:42.910209+1200    mediaserverd    CAReportingClient.mm:470:-[CAReportingClient sendMessage:category:type:reporters:]: message {
    "inf_frames" = 0;
    "issue_type" = NonFinite;
    "nan_frames" = 1083;
    node = "PostDSP - { [ type: phpw; conn: 1; rout: 1 ] }";
    "rtaid_client" = VA;
}: (
    133143986217
)
default 20:32:42.911062+1200    mediaserverd    AudioIssueDetectorManager.cpp:250:HandleAudioIssue: RTAID [ use_case=Generic issue_type=NonFinites clientID=VA node=PostDSP - { [ type: phpw; conn: 1; rout: 1 ] } ] -- [ nan_frames=1083 inf_frames=0 ]
default 20:32:42.913038+1200    rtcreportingd   sendMessageWithDictionary: Sending message for session 41
default 20:32:42.913957+1200    rtcreportingd   <private>(sendMessage): realtime is 0
default 20:32:42.914127+1200    rtcreportingd   <private>(sendMessage): Batching 3, 1, 1
default 20:32:42.935883+1200    sharingd    Identification starting maintenance timer
default 20:32:42.937060+1200    rapportd    BLE device changed: SFDevice ID a6207782-86f9-e3fe-2ca2-fc6f74e80bd4, IDS B710183A, RSSI -47 (-44)*N, Nm 'Tomas’s MacBook Pro', Md 'MacBookPro16,1', DuetSync, PairedBT, PairedSys Conjectured, rapportID B710183A-9C32-45F2-B698-72BBC69FED93, WiFiP2P, DF 0x88 < MyiCloud AirDrop >
default 20:32:42.938332+1200    sharingd    CompanionLink changed: IDS B710183A, Nm 'Tomas’s MacBook Pro', Md 'MacBookPro16,1'
default 20:32:43.009206+1200    powerlogHelperd {"msg":"CLCopyAppsUsingLocation", "event":"activity"}
default 20:32:43.038177+1200    nsurlsessiond   Triggering periodic update to powerlog for client <private>
default 20:32:43.260560+1200    DTServiceHub    Heartbeat
```

Comment: Do other apps stop making sound at the same time this one does? I'm just wondering if the phone is deciding to conserve power by shutting down audio.